# Same if statement works for one situation but fails for another similar one?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I got some code like this:

```
require 'nokogiri'

class Parser
  def self.parse(html)
    @data = Nokogiri.HTML(open(html))
    merged_hashes = {}

    array_of_hashes = [
      parse_department,
      parse_super_saver,
      parse_new_arrivals,
      parse_out_of_stock,
      parse_categories,
      parse_results,
      parse_category
    ]
    array_of_hashes.inject(merged_hashes,:update)

    return merged_hashes
  end

  ## Categories

  (etc...)  

  def self.parse_results
    results = @data.css('#refinements ul').first
    unless results
      @results_hash = {}
      return @results_hash
    end

    if results.css('li:nth-child(1) a span').text == "Pet Supplies"
      @results_hash = {}
      @results_hash[:results] ||= {}
      @results_hash[:results] = @data.at_css('#resultCount span').text[/(\S+) Results$/i, 1].delete(",").to_i
    else
      @results_hash = {}
    end

    return @results_hash
  end

  ## Hot Lists

  def self.parse_category
    category = @data.at_css('#zg_listTitle span')

    unless category
      @category_hash = {}
      return @category_hash
    end

    @category_hash = {}
    @category_hash[:category] ||= {}
    @category_hash[:category] = @data.at_css('#zg_listTitle span').text

    return @category_hash
  end
end
```

This works OK:

```
    results = @data.css('#refinements ul').first
    unless results
      @results_hash = {}
      return @results_hash
    end
```

When there isn't a `#refinements ul` element, the code stops and an empty ash is returned.

But in the case of

```
    category = @data.at_css('#zg_listTitle span')
    unless category
      @category_hash = {}
      return @category_hash
    end
```

The code seems to continue even though there isn't any `#zg_listTitle span` element.

What could be the problem?

**EDIT:**

Rspec:

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/parser.rb'

def html_pet_supplies
  File.open("parse_categories/amazon_pet_supplies.html")
end

def html_dog_supplies
  File.open("parse_categories/amazon_dog_supplies.html")
end

def html_bird_supplies
  File.open("parse_categories/amazon_bird_supplies.html")
end

def html_baby
  File.open("parse_hotlists/amazon_baby.html")
end

(etc.)

describe "Results (Dogs)" do
  let(:results_hash) { Parser.parse html_dog_supplies } 

  it "should return correct hash" do
    expect(results_hash[:results]).to eq(514265)
  end
end


## Hot Lists

describe "Category" do
  let(:category_hash) { Parser.parse html_baby } 

  it "should return correct hash" do
    expect(category_hash[:category]).to eq("Baby")
  end
end
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Adding a enough of the html to reproduce the problem would really help.

Comment: And remove all extraneous code, leaving ONLY code necessary to reproduce the problem. See http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the `#zg_listTitle span` not found then, `@data.at_css('#zg_listTitle span')` will return `nil`. So I think you need to use `if` instead of `unless`.

```
category = @data.at_css('#zg_listTitle span')
if category
  @category_hash = {}
  return @category_hash
end
```

Comment: When `#zg_listTitle span` is `nil` the code should stop. If it's something else than `nil` it should proceed. I think unless is alright here.

Comment: @alexchenco No you are a bit confused I think.. :)

Comment: the whole point for that unless statement is to stop the code if `category is nil` so it reads: "trigger this code to stop everything **unless** category is something else than nil" Am I confusing something here?

Comment: @alexchenco yes.. think that way.. `if true then "done"` is valid.. But when you want to execute the code `"done"` with `nil` or `false` value..then you need to write `if !true then "code"` but instead writing that we write `unless false then "done"`